# Select/Copy Collapsed Folding group without expansion

Tags: notepad++

Notepad++ supports folding: [code folding](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/display/folding)

How do I copy the folded text as it appears on the screen without expansion?

I am creating documentation and only want to copy/paste what is on the screen, not the expanded code that is folded up.

Comment: Just select and copy as normal.

Comment: Paste in that case includes expanded/hidden material. Need unexpanded paste.

Comment: No it doesn't. I tested it.